# WSO2 lags in processing fixed-time APIs

Tags: wso2-api-manager, apache-axis, wso2

We have a backend API which runs in almost constant time (it does "sleep" for given period). When we run a managed API which proxies to it for a long time, we see that from time to time its execution time increases up to twice the average.

From analyzing the Amazon ALB data in production, it seems that the time the request spends inside Synapse remains the same, but the connection time (the time the request enters the queue for processing) is high.

In an isolated environment we noticed that those lags happen approximately every 10 minutes. In production, where we have multiple workers that gets request all the time, the picture is more obscured, as it happens more often (possibly the lag accumulates).

Does anyone aware of any periodic activity in the worker which result delays entering the queue every
few minutes? Any parameter that control this? Otherwise, any idea how to figure out what is the cause?

Attached is an image demonstrating it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could be due to gateway token cache invalidation. The default timeout is 15 minutes.

Once the key validation is done via the Key Manager, the key validation info is cached in the gateway. The subsequent API invocations, key validation will be done from this cache. During this time, the execution time will be lower.

After the cache invalidation, the token validation will be done via the key manager (using DB). This will cause an increase in the execution time.

Comment: Question is will it happen also if we are not working with key manager? We have our own authentication handler which replaces the standard WSO2 authentication handler, and all our APIs are defined as "Unauthenticated" to WSO2, so no WSO2 token is sent.

Answer (score 0):

Investigating further, we found out two causes for the spikes.

1. Our handler writes log to shared file system which was set as sync instead of async. This caused delays. This reduced most of the spikes.
2. Additional spikes seem to be related to registry updates. We did not investigate those, as they were more sporadic.